# Used Duplicator to transfer a site. Now my media uploads aren't working

Tags: uploads, media, permissions

I deleted an image from the Media tab and when I tried to upload another, I started getting this error:

```
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2014/10
```

I tried CHMODing the `wp-content` and `uploads` folder to 777; however, I still get the same error.

Note: I used the Duplicator plugin to move the site from one server to another. I'm not sure if this has something to do with my problem but I'm mentioning it just in case. The media uploads worked fine before transferring everything over.

Comment: Make sure all the image files exists in `wp-content/uploads/2014/10` if not then upload them manually.

Comment: you should check the permissions of the 2014 and 10 folders as well

Comment: @Robert There are so far no images in that folder. I'm trying to upload the first one.

Comment: @Mark Does this mean that I have to always keep the `wp-content`, `uploads`, `2014`, and `10` folders to `777`? Isn't that unsafe? Not sure why I was able to upload fine with `755` before the transfer.

Comment: @Desi, uploads and whatever is below it should be 777, wp-content should be more restricted permissions.

Comment: @Mark Is there a way to make sure that all month folders created from here on out gets automatically permissioned to 777? Before they were being created as 755 and everything worked fine so I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: most ftp tools, can change permissions recursively.